# create multiple span inside div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have one image, when I am clicking on that image, I am getting one textbox and a button. By clicking on button, I want to put that textbox values in separate spans inside a div with id demo. 
Ho I can do that using javascript only?

Here is the function in which I was trying the same(I am trying so lots of error must be there)

```
function addTag(){

            var text = document.getElementById('title').value;
            //console.log(text);
            var demoid = document.getElementById('demo');
            console.log(demoid);

            var spa = document.createElement('span');
            spa.id = text;
            spa.appendChild(demoid);
            var text = text+' , ';
            spa.innerHTML = text;
            console.log(spa.id);

            jQuery("#form_panel").hide();
            jQuery("#someID").hide();

            console.log("in addTag");

        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like following using jQuery:

```
$('button').on('click',function (e) {
     $('#demo').append('<span>'+$('textbox').val()+'</span>');
 });
```

Answer (score 12):

To create a span element in javascript:

```
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
```

Add it to the DOM tree in the right place, say inside the 'demo' div:

```
document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(newSpan);
```

So a textbox in a span in that div:

```
var newTextbox = document.createElement('input');
newTextbox.type = 'textbox';
var newSpan = document.createElement('span');
var demodiv = document.getElementById('demo');

newSpan.appendChild(newTextbox);
demodiv.appendChild(newSpan);

console.log(demodiv.innerHTML);
```

Console yields:

```
<span><input type=\"textbox\"></span>
```

The alternative is to construct a complete chunk of HTML (performance may vary):

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML += "<span><input type='textbox'></span>";
```

-- Edit after seeing your code --

It looks like you are doing `spanElement.appendChild(divElement)`, but that is attempting to  insert the div inside the span. You want to insert the span into the div, so you need `divElement.appendChild(spanElement)`.

Comment: I already have text box, and i want to add  that text box value in new span in #demo div whenever i will click on button after text box.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Javascript functions `createElement()` and `appendChild()` will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You better use jQuery.

You can use $.add() or $.append() functions.

Visit https://api.jquery.com/append/ for more information.

Hope this will help you!!